# Testing Neural Net Model with Different Dummy Variables Shape/Size

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, dummy-variable

Assume that I have the following training set;

Training Set:

[image: Sample Training Dataset]

Note that F1, F2, F3, and F4 represents the features, and D1, D2, D3 are the output. So it is a multi class classification problem.

I want to develop a multi class classification neural net, so I have created dummy variables for output, the updated training set looks like the following;

Updated Training Set:

[image: Updated Data with Dummy Variables]

I used keras to develop a neural net and saved the resultant model to "model.h5"

Now I want to test the model with the following data set;
Test Set:

[image: Test Set]

I created dummy variables, the resultant data set has the following form;

Updated Test Set

[image: Test Set with Dummy Variables]

The test data set dummy variables have different shape and order than training set. How can I use the test set to find the accuracy of my model?

Comment: In the testing dataset, add a column of D3 with zeros and then test it

Comment: Also, for the test dataset (with output = D2, D1,...), you can use sparse_categoricalcrossentropy loss to test on it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The first suggestion is useful.
Regarding the second suggestion, it will require redesigning the model based on sparse_categorical_crossentropy. 

Is there a way to avoid it? The only solution that comes into mind is to find the unique values in the third table (test set),  create dummy variables, add missing cols (such as as D3 with zeroes values) and then re-order them based on the training data set (first table).

Comment: For the 2nd one: You could do without redisigning the model. You have to take the predictions using F1, F2, ... and then compare the predictions with Output(=D1,D2,..) using sparse_categorical_crossentropy without any changes in model. You could refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/sparse_categorical_crossentropy). But the losses during your training and this one may differ, making it hard to interpret what's going on, so I would not recommend this now.